# Managing an Arduino project involving multiple boards

Tags: arduino, include, arduino-ide

How would I go about easily managing an Arduino project that has multiple sketches(project/sketch_)/sketch_0.ino; project/sketch_1/sketch_1.ino; ecc.) for multiple boards with a unique configuration .h file?

I've already tried

```
#include "../config.h"

...
```

or

```
#include <../config.h>

...
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that file in the libraries folder in a folder called "config" and then you can use it in each of your programs like a regular library.  You might consider giving it a slightly more unique name though in case you want to do a similar thing with other projects.  Just make sure the folder it's in has the same name as the .h file and it's in the user libraries folder for the IDE.